# Is possible to use the browser storage as a data repository?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, repository, local-storage

With Javascript, exist some way to do a data repository (like the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) for example), using the local storage of the browser? If exist, which compatibility issues between browsers will be found?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you are looking for:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

It explains how to use the local storage on newer browsers(HTML 5 enabled) without the need for cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to save data on browser storage.
other things you can do is using other ways to control that.

**1st Way:**

data you need to save for the entire session of the user you can globalize in your web by just declaring it as Global variable.

**2nd Way**

You can use the jQuery plugin called Cookie, you can find it in [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

cookie will basically means saving for a longer term then the session. and it is ,in fact,  saving data on the user's computer.

My personal suggestion : if you absolutely need to save data and a lot of it in a way, i would either suggest you to save it on your sever (if you have any) or by cookie.

If this answer wasn't enough satisfying for you, please comment and i will try to be more accurate and helpful.